# Why do we use combinations rather than permutations when calculating sample points

Tags: probability, combinatorics, hypergeometric-distribution

Let me state a question to use as an example:

Suppose I have 3 blue marbles and 4 red marbles. Suppose we take 5 marbles from this without replacement. What would be the pdf of the random variable Y if Y is the number of blue marbles among the 5 selected marbles.

We assign each marble a number 1,2,3,...,7.

Now after this, we start to find the number of combinations. So Y=2 has associated sample points: 12456,12457, etc
and the number of these is $n_2$ = $C^3 _2$$C^4 _3$ 
and we would calculate the number of sample points as $n_s$= $C^9 _5$

My question would be, why do we calculate the combinations rather than the permutations of these events? I would think that 12456 would be a different event to 14256 and need to be counted twice in the same way that flipping a coin 3 times and getting Head Head Tails is a seperate event from Tails Head Head. So if we count the coin example as 2 sample points, because of difference in order, why don't we do the same for the marble questions?

Comment: Your phrasing "take 5 marbles" says nothing about taking them in any particular order. So let's turn your question on its head: why do you even introduce an order into a problem where order plays no role?

Comment: Suppose I ask: "Whats the probability of getting 2 heads on 3 coin flips?" Then I would calculate Head Tails Head aswell as all its permutations, despite not once having mentioned anything about order. Why isn't this true for the marbles then?

Comment: The sample space for the coin flips has eight elements and this question asks about an event that has three elements.  Order is still not necessary for reasoning about the question, nor for finding the answer.